# Mac Mail.app (Yosemite) - preview pane on right WITHOUT individual message previews on left

Tags: mail.app

I want something simple - and I have found how to have preview pane on right (as opposed to bottom half of screen) OR remove individual message previews in the email list - but not both.

I just want a list of messages on the left (without preview of their text) - and to show the message on the right. This is simple in Thunderbird - but apparently impossible in Mac mail?

Can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Yosemite (I'm on 10.10.1) I can do the following:

- Mail > Preferences…
- Viewing Tab

  1. Uncheck "Use classic layout"
  2. Uncheck To/CC label in message list
  3. Uncheck Contact photos in message list
  4. List Preview: None

In my toggling of options, the message pane itself disappeared. However it was made available via a grab handle at the right edge of the screen. I now have a message list showing me no previews and a message pane to the right of that.

Comment: Thanks; nailed it. Actually my message pane didn't disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Open Mail preference and uncheck the Use Classic box in the View tab.

Now you will see the list of all messages without any preview.

Next one is bit hidden (do not know why)

On the right side of the mail window you will see a thicker vertical border line.

Click on it and it will now show you the preview on the right side while the messages are showing as a list to the left of it.

Comment: When I uncheck the 'use classic' box - I get individual message previews on the left (that is some of the text of each email appears under it). I find that very visually cluttered and can see far fewer emails. I would like to get rid of the individual preview text.

Answer (score 1):

In mail preference, I clicked 'use classic' in view box. Then went to the email window, grabbed the line at the top of the preview of the mail message and pulled it down to the bottom to close the preview pane. Then you will have only two columns, the mailbox column and the email messages list.

Comment: This isn't what I want to do. I want an email list without the preview text - and the right hand preview pane of the emails. You can do this in Thunderbird.